# Force ruby to use dbi Gem instead of dbi in site_ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm using:

- Windows 7
- Ruby 1.8.6 One-Click Installer
- DBI version 0.4.3 installed using RubyGems

What I see when executing these commands:

> C:>ruby -v
>
> ruby 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287) [i386-mswin32]
>
> C:>gem -v
>
> 1.3.1
>
> C:>ruby -r rubygems -r dbi -e "puts DBI::VERSION"
>
> 0.2.2
>
> C:>gem list dbi
>
> *** LOCAL GEMS ***
>
> dbi (0.4.3)
>
> C:>gem environment
>
> RubyGems Environment:
>
> - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.1
> - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287) [i386-mswin32]
> - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
> - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe
> - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby/bin
> - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
>
>   - ruby
>   - x86-mswin32-60
> - GEM PATHS:
>
>   - C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
>   - C:/Users/sutch/.gem/ruby/1.8
> - GEM CONFIGURATION:
>
>   - :update_sources => true
>   - :verbose => true
>   - :benchmark => false
>   - :backtrace => false
>   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
> - REMOTE SOURCES:
>
>   - http://gems.rubyforge.org/

Why do ruby scripts use the DBI installed in site_ruby rather than the DBI installed with RubyGems?

---

### Update to respond to Luis Lavena's answer...

Here's what happened when I attempted what you suggest:

> C:>ruby -r rubygems -e "require 'rubygems'; puts DBI::VERSION"
>
> -e:1: uninitialized constant DBI (NameError)

And when I updated to require DBI:

> C:>ruby -r rubygems -e "require 'rubygems' ; require 'dbi' ; puts DBI::VERSION"
>
> 0.2.2

Why wouldn't RubyGems override the built-in library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ruby -r` you're using Ruby builtin require instead of the one redefined by RubyGems.

Try this:

```
ruby -r rubygems -e "require 'dbi'; puts DBI::VERSION"
```

That should do the trick.

FYI: this has been improved in newer versions of Ruby (1.9 versions, none of the 1.8 has this behavior).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I attempted what you suggest (see updated question above) and Ruby/RubyGems still uses the built-in DBI.  Why would RubyGems not use it's version, which is the latest version of DBI?

Comment: You're correct, I forgot to mention that you need to require DBI too.

Comment: RubyGems will always give priority to libraries installed in site_ruby, see this: http://gist.github.com/342220

You can remove bundled DBI from site_ruby and it will pick up the gem. Also, you can use Rubyinstaller instead, which do not bundle any library :-)